# Use of window.hasOwnProperty()

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a speech recognition in html. I am taking help from [labnol.org](https://www.labnol.org/software/add-speech-recognition-to-website/19989/). While doing so, I faced a problem. I don't what is the use of `window.hasOwnProperty('webkitSpeechRecognition')`. Can anyone please tell me what is its use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is checking whether `window` (the global object) has a property called `webkitSpeechRecognition`, i.e. is [Webkit Speech Recognition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API#Browser_compatibility) supported.